# Numeric comparison CMD issue

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The if statement here does not work.Why? I mean the SID ends with 502 and it enters the first condition like 502 is greater than 1000. **-UPDATE : So it seems that this is a length problem.The number of the digits must be equal on both sides of the comparison.How do I force them to be equal length ?**

```
 @ECHO OFF
    ECHO PROGRAMA DE USUARIOS
    for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('wmic useraccount get name') do (
        if %%a GTR 0 (
            for /f "tokens=8 delims=-" %%b in ('wmic useraccount where name^="%%a" get sid') do (
                echo User Accounts:
                if %%b GEQ 1000 (
                    echo NAME
                    echo %%a
                    wmic useraccount where name^="%%a" get sid
                    echo %%b
                )
            )
        )
    )
    for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('wmic useraccount get name') do (
        if %%a GTR 0 (
            for /f "tokens=8 delims=-" %%b in ('wmic useraccount where name^="%%a" get sid') do (
                echo System Accounts:
                if %%b LSS 1000 (
                    echo NAME
                    echo %%a
                    wmic useraccount where name^="%%a" get sid
                    echo %%b
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of string comparison. You need set variable to number with SET /A

```
for /f "tokens=8 delims=-" %%b in ('echo S-1-5-21-2685429265-1343094091-1357998488-3175') do (set /A NUM=%%b) 
if %NUM% LSS 1000 (echo less)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the information retrived from the `wmic` command includes ending spaces (at least it does it in my machine for the `sid` field) and a final carriage return at the end of each line (a known *"problem"*  in `wmic` output) that will be retrieved into the `for` replaceable parameter.

In this case, the simplest solution is to change the query to the `wmic` to retrieve the data in `csv` format and include an additional unneeded field that will be not processed which will prevent our code from retrieving the ending carriage in the output of the `wmic` command

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    echo PROGRAMA DE USUARIOS
    echo(

    echo Cuentas de usuario:
    call :showAccounts 
    echo(

    echo Cuentas de sistema:
    call :showAccounts system
    echo(

    goto :eof

:showAccounts [system]
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    if /i "%~1"=="system" ( 
        set "condition=LSS 1000" 
    ) else ( 
        set "condition=GEQ 1000"
    )

    for /f "skip=1 tokens=2,3 delims=," %%a in ('
        wmic useraccount get name^,sid^,status /format:csv
    ') do for /f "tokens=8 delims=-" %%c in ("%%b") do (
        if %%c %condition% (
            echo(    Name: %%a
            echo(    SID : %%b
        )
    )

    goto :eof
```

To avoid repetition of the code, the information retrieval has been moved to a subroutine and called twice to retrieve the user and system accounts (not needed, just an habit, I don't like duplicating code).

User or System accounts will be shown depending on the presence of the string `system` as first argument to the subroutine call. A variable is defined to contain the condition to match.

Instead of executing one query to retrieve the account list and one query for each of the accounts to retrieve the `sid`, the `wmic` query has been changed to retrieve both fields. To do so, the commas need to be escaped (the `^`s) to be included inside the `for /f` command.

The `csv` output is processed using the commas in the lines as delimiters and the token numbers have changed. The `csv` format will include the machine name (`node` field) as first field, so we need to process tokens 2 (`name`) and 3 (`sid`).

In `csv` format the fields (except the first one, always the `node`) are sorted alphabetically. To avoid the inclusion of the last carriage return in the `sid` field, the `Status` field (`status` gtr `sid`) has also been requested.